# Bootstrap rendering different on server

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, rendering

I'm making a Django application using Bootstrap for styling, and I have an inconsistency between my computer and the server regarding how the page renders.

**Local:**

[image]

**Server:**

[image]

The upper black stripe is a navbar.

Code:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">OSV</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Realizar Busqueda</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
                <form  action="{% url 'buscador_ingresar_calle' %}" method="get">
                    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                    {% for field in form %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ field.errors }}
                                <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                            {{ field }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-blue btn-lg btn-block">Enviar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try hard refresh (ctrl + F5) on localhost?

Comment: How did you render the "local" version?

Comment: With django's development server. On the server I'm using nginx and gunicorn.

Comment: Where is your include for bootstrap?

Comment: First, make sure that your site is not cached (clean cache, shift + f5, etc). If that does not work, check with the inspector that your styles are being loaded, if they are not you may be missing collectstatic or may be referencing an old CSS.

Comment: Yes, after a while I realized chrome was caching an old version of the css file. Thank you.